# Regex - Excluding a particular String in R?

Tags: regex, rscript

I am trying to search a particular keyword "ME", in different combinations as per the regex throughout the length of the corpus, (with i being the iterator in the loop till the length of the corpus). As a result I am having ME as qualifications in most of the Resumes in the corpus, as an example:-
1. ME
2. M.E in Electronics
3. M.E.
4. ME.-Computer Science etc.

```
 matchME <- regmatches(as.String(docs[[i]]), gregexpr("\\WM\\.?E\\.?(\\s|\\.|\\-|\\(|\\:|\\,)|((Master)|(MASTER))[sS]?\\s?(((of)|(Of)|(OF))|((in)|(In)|(IN)))\\s?((Engineering)|(ENGINEERING)|(Engg)|(engineering))" , as.String(docs[[i]])))
```

However, I am getting a result for "Windows - ME" for people who have worked on the platform but have not done the qualification in a lot of documents. I want this particular set to be removed. So I am trying to build the following regex which will not include "Windows- ME" or "Windows ME" etc combinations, but it doesn't seem to work

```
[^(Windows)]\WM\.?E\.?(\s|\.|\-|\(|\:|\,)|((Master)|(MASTER))[sS]?\s?(((of)|(Of)|(OF))|((in)|(In)|(IN)))\s?((Engineering)|(ENGINEERING)|(Engg)|(engineering))
```

Comment: Excluding a string can be done with a negative lookahead, like `(?!Win(?:dows)?\\s*-\\s*ME)` at the beginning of the pattern, and adding `perl=T`. Besides, you could use `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern to turn on case-insensitive matching.